# keycloak integration with Azure AD for webapp authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, keycloak

I am trying to use keycloak for saml broking between my web application and IDP Azure AD.

I have created few users in Azure AD and added my webapp as Application there.
I have configured KeyCloak with SAML IDP and imported Azure AD federation data in Keycloak.

But somewhere something is wrong as I did not get any link on web which can give me step by step process to integrate KeyCloak with Azure AD.

I am getting Microsoft login page and on putting password authentication is getting passed but then I get the following error before it redirects back to Keycloak:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> > AADSTS700016: Application with identifier
> >     'http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/localRealm' was not found in the
> >     directory '<>'. This can happen if
> >     the application has not been installed by the administrator of the
> >     tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent
> >     your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I used the below 2 links to do the configuration:

https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/okta-saml/  This link describes how to configure Keycloak with Okta for SAML

https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/1-5/azure/config-azure.html  This link describes how to configure Azure AD as SAML IDP

Edit: It looks like Keycloak is sending wrong application identifier in SAML (maybe) as this localhost:8280... is Keycloak Realm URL and not the Azure Application Identifier which is some string key in Azure -> Applications

Answer (score 6):

I believe there might be 2 things you are missing:

1. The `App ID URI` field in the Azure AD app registration properties must be replaced with the Redirect URI of the Keycloak identity provider, **but** without the "/broker/...../endpoint" part at the end.

For example, if your identity provider was named `myprovider` for realm named `myrealm`, your Redirect URI probably looks like this `https://mykeycloakserver/auth/realms/myrealm/broker/myprovider/endpoint`, so the value you need to use in Azure AD for the App ID URI would look like: `https://mykeycloakserver/auth/realms/myrealm`

2. Make sure the full keycloak redirect url is listed as one of the "Reply URLs" in the Azure AD app registration.

PS - the APP ID URI property of the app is not (currently, as of 2019/04) available in the App Registrations (preview) panel - you need to go to App Registrations > {app name} > Settings > Properties

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If your Keycloak logs are similar to mine, which had something similar to `Assertion _5c69599c-cf6a-4965-934c-6221a6b8a800 is not addressed to this SP`.

The solution in my scenario, when trying to connect to Microsoft Azure AD SAML, was to:

1. On https://portal.azure.com/, set the `Application ID URI` to `https://<host>.co/auth/realms/<realm>`
2. On the Keycloak instance, in the IdP configuration, the `Service Provider Entity ID` in the Keycloak settings also to `https://<host>.co/auth/realms/<realm>`.

Answer (score -2):

Creating a new realm in Keycloak and trying out helped!